# How to parse the gerrit query json output using python and print couple of items?

Tags: python

This prints the gerrit owner's name:

```
ssh -p $PORT $HOST gerrit query --format=JSON change:12345 | head -n 1 | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['owner']['name']"
```

this prints email:

```
ssh -p $PORT $HOST gerrit query --format=JSON change:12345 | head -n 1 | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['owner']['email']"
```

How to make it print `"name <email>"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['owner']['name'] + '<' + json.load(sys.stdin)['owner']['email'] + '>'"`

You can add strings using `+`

And this can be shortened using a variable:

```
python -c "import sys, json; o = json.load(sys.stdin)['owner']; print o['name'] + '<' + o['email'] + '>'"
```